# Provide dataset schema for ADF CosmosDB dataset via terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-data-factory

I want to provide dataset schema with terraform for my `azurerm_data_factory_dataset_cosmosdb_sqlapi` resource.

I tried to specify schema with `schema_column` attribute with the following syntax

```
schema_column {
  name = "id"
  type = "String"
}
```

but it doesn't apply any changes.

Providing `structure` with `additional_parameters` fails as it expects values as string instead of array.

```
additional_parameters = {
  "structure": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "type": "String"
    }
  ]
}
```

What is the correct way to specify schema with terraform?

These are resources I used:

1. https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/data_factory_dataset_cosmosdb_sqlapi
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-azure-documentdb-connector#schema-by-data-factory

Answer (score 0):

*I also got the same error when I tried in my environment as shown.*

[image]

After a workaround on this, I modified the `additional_properities` block by passing `structure as jsonencode`.

```bash
additional_properties = {
    "structure": jsonencode([
      {
        "name": "id",
        "type": "String"
      }
    ])
    }
```

***Complete tf script attached below:***

```bash
provider "azurerm"{
features{}
}
data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "resourcegroup"
}

resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_account" "main" {
  name                = "xxx"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  offer_type          = "Standard"
  kind                = ""

  enable_automatic_failover = true

  capabilities {
    name = ""
  }

  capabilities {
    name = ""
  }

  capabilities {
    name = "MongoDBv3.4"
  }

  consistency_policy {
    consistency_level       = "BoundedStaleness"
    max_interval_in_seconds = xxx
    max_staleness_prefix    = xxx
  }

  geo_location {
    location          = ""
    failover_priority = 1
  }

  geo_location {
    location          = ""
    failover_priority = 0
  }
}

resource "azurerm_data_factory" "main" {
  name                = "exampledf"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_data_factory_linked_service_cosmosdb" "main" {
  name             = "example"
  data_factory_id  = azurerm_data_factory.main.id
  account_endpoint = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.main.endpoint
  database         = "xxxx"
}

resource "azurerm_data_factory_dataset_cosmosdb_sqlapi" "example" {
  name                = "exampledsc"
  data_factory_id     = azurerm_data_factory.main.id
  linked_service_name = azurerm_data_factory_linked_service_cosmosdb.main.name

  collection_name = "bar"
  additional_properties = {
    "structure": jsonencode([
      {
        "name": "id",
        "type": "String"
      }
    ])
}
}
```

***Executed*** `terraform init`:

[image]

***Executed*** `terraform plan`:

[image]

***Executed*** `terraform apply`:

[image]

Refer [terraform registry](https://registry.terraform.io/) for the sample structure of the templates.

Comment: terraform apply runs without errors, but the problem still remains, dataset schema not updated in the adf